# How to set TrackExceptionsAsExceptionTelemetry in Azure Functions?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I have application insights connected to my azure functions and use default ILogger for logging.

With default configuration, if you pass an exception in a code such as

```
log.logError(ex, "Some message")
```

it will result in both trace entry and an exception entry.

I would like to disable this behavior, so that only unhandled exceptions are captured by AI as an exception entry.

Docs say here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger) that to achieve that I need setup the AI like this:

```
builder.AddApplicationInsights(
    options => options.TrackExceptionsAsExceptionTelemetry = false);
```

however it seems it cannot be done in Azure Functions.

For starters I use built-in ILogger support, so I do not explicitly add AI in Startup.cs but even if I did, in the library there is no such method at all but rather `builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry` that doesn't have such TrackExceptionsAsExceptionTelemetry property in the options.

I know that a workaround would be to log something like
`log.logError($"Some message, {ex.Message}, {ex.StackTrace}")` but maybe there is some better solution?

Comment: How do you connect your function to app insights? code-based or code-less?

Comment: code-less, so just by having APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY in the configuration, the AI automatically picks it up and works

Comment: I just used `builder.Services.Configure<ApplicationInsightsLoggerOptions>(o => o.TrackExceptionsAsExceptionTelemetry = false);` in my Startup but it didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

For my testing, I created the app insights alongside the function, and a default http trigger. I found that the handled exception will logged by trace and there was no exception entry indeed. If I didn't surround with `try catch`, I got the exception entry. Did I misunderstand in some place?

[image]
[image]
[image]

==========================Update==========================

If enabled app insights by code, per my testing, I got the same situation as you, like my screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: That's weird, in your setup it works just as I want it to be. But even in MS docs in the page I linked there is a note "If an Exception object is passed to the Log method on ILogger, ExceptionTelemetry is created instead of TraceTelemetry.", so I wonder how did you get it working like that.

Comment: I think it comes back to the question, how did you connect app insights to your function. Hmmm, I [created app insights when I creating my function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#application-insights-integration), and there's no any other configurations or code. https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIyV6.png

Comment: I mean that the link you provided referred to the asp.net web application and it's not suitable for azure function. And I haven't found the solution to solve the duplicated exception trace based on package -- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights